# Can I change object without using object reference as well as in non-static context?

Tags: java, function, object, methods

In code,What is the difference of calling in main?

- `input.reverseArray(input);`
- `reverseArray(input);`
- `input = reverseArray(input);`
- `input =input.reverseArray(input);`

Finally, Would these be applicable if reverseArray was not static?

---

```
public class reverse
{
     
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int [] input = new int[]{4, 5, 8, 9, 10};      
    }
    public static void reverseArray(int inputArray[])
        {
            
             
            int temp;
             
            for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length/2; i++) 
            {
                temp = inputArray[i];
                 
                inputArray[i] = inputArray[inputArray.length-1-i];
                 
                inputArray[inputArray.length-1-i] = temp;
            }
             
            
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `input.reverseArray(input);` doesn't compile because `reverseArray` is not a method defined by the type of `input`, namely `int[]`.
- `reverseArray(input);` compiles and works correctly.
- `input = reverseArray(input);` doesn't compile because `reverseArray` returns `void`, so it can't be assigned to `input`.
- `input =input.reverseArray(input);` doesn't compile for both of the above reasons.

If `reverseArray` were not static, then none of the above would compile. In particular, `reverseArray(input)` is called from a *static context* (i.e., from a `static` method) in a *static way* (without using an object as in `foo.reverseArray(input)`), but `reverseArray` is *not static*. The way to call `reverseArray` is to use an object of type `reverse`, since the `reverse` class defines the method `reverseArray`:

```
reverse myReverse = new reverse();
myReverse.reverseArray(input);
```

Also note that by Java convention, classes should be named in CamelCase, so you should change `reverse` to `Reverse`.